# Using Dart and Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dart, project-structure

I'm experimenting with Dart and am now trying to use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for its CSS framework. When I download the latest version of Bootstrap (currently 3.0.3), it has the following file structure:

```
├── css
│   ├── bootstrap.css
│   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   ├── bootstrap-theme.css
│   └── bootstrap-theme.min.css
├── fonts
│   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
│   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
│   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
│   └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
└── js
    ├── bootstrap.js
    └── bootstrap.min.js
```

**(1) Where do I put all these files, and how do I access them from inside BOTH my Dart source and HTML files?** For example, say I want to dynamically change the DOM from inside a Dart file, and add a Bootstrap class to an element - what would this look like? And if I just wanted to give an HTML element a Bootstrap class (inside a .html file), what would this look like?

I *assume* I might need a Dart project with a package structure *something* like this:

```
MyDartApp/
    web/
        myapp.dart
    asset/
        bootstrap/
            css/
                bootstrap.css
                bootstrap.min.css
                bootstrap-theme.css
                bootstrap-them.min.css
            fonts/
                glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
                glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
                glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
                glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
            js/
                bootstrap.js
                bootstrap.min.js
```

But having such little experience with both Dart and Bootstrap, not sure if I am missing anything big. Obviously, I need to package the Bootstrap files in such a way that the `asset/` URLs in my Dart/HTML files can access them before/after running `pub build`.

**(2) Also, can I just use the `min`-version of each CSS/JS file (`bootstrap.min.js` instead of `bootstrap.js`, etc.)?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. you can use the `asset/` folder to put these files. However the builtin server in the editor does not support asset for now, you will have to use `pub serve`. To access them use `/assets/<pkg_name>/<path>` (see [How to refer to assets](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/assets-and-transformers.html#how-to-refer-to-assets)). Alternatively you can put those files under `/lib/` and access them with `packages/<pkg_name>/<path>`.
2. you can use minified versions.

Comment: Thanks @Alexandre Ardhuin - one quick followup: you mentioned that `pub serve` supports `asset`, but what about `pub build`? Thanks again!

Comment: `pub build` also supports _assets_. I only mention `pub serve` because it's the equivalent to the Dart Editor builtin server.

Comment: `asset/` directory is no longer supported. The same link [How to refer to assets](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/assets-and-transformers.html#how-to-refer-to-assets) is updated with the new information.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using [bookjack](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/bootjack) which so far has been fine.

> Usage First of all in your HTML file, you need to include the CSS
>   resource:

```
  <head><link rel="stylesheet" href="packages/bootjack/css/bootstrap.min.css"> </head>
```

There are also some further [examples](https://github.com/rikulo/bootjack/tree/master/example).

Using it like this seems to help keep the project simpler, in that I don't have to worry about where the files actually are, they are in a package.

Comment: Can you use all of bootstrap components?

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I am using Angular Dart and in the view I can do this and it works, but it has to be within the view where the

```
<div id="datepicker-inline"></div>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
   console.log($('#datepicker-inline').get(0));
   $('#datepicker-inline').bdatepicker({ inline: true, showOtherMonths:true });
});
</script>
```